# Helpers for i18n translation of model attributes outside of form_for?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a model called `Presentation`. It has all its attributes named in my i18n locale files, under `activerecord.attributes.presentation`.

I want to create an index view for this model, in the form of a table overview. The code for this currently looks like this:

```
<table class="table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th><%= t('activerecord.attributes.presentation.title') %></th>
      <th><%= t('activerecord.attributes.presentation.default_duration') %></th>
      <th><%= t('activerecord.attributes.presentation.bg_color') %></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>

  <tbody>
    <%= render @presentations %>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

which works okay, but having to write out the full key doesn't really seem the Rails way to me. It also won't fail in any noticeable way if the translation is missing, or no such attribute of the model exists.

`<%= f.label :title %>`? inside a `form_for` block automatically outputs the translated attribute name as a label based on just a symbol. Are there any sort of view helpers that work the same way, but outside of forms? Something like this (this is not the best code example, I'm aware):

```
<%= attributes_of User do |attr| %>
  <th><%= attr.t :title %></th>
  <th><%= attr.t :default_duration %></th>
  <th><%= attr.t :bg_color %></th>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The best you can do is:

```
<% I18n.with_options(scope: 'activerecord.attributes.presentation') do |i18n| %>
  <table class="table">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th><%= i18n.t :title %></th>
        <th><%= i18n.t :default_duration %></th>
        <th><%= i18n.t :bg_color %></th>
      </tr>
    </thead>

    <tbody>
      <%= render @presentations %>
    </tbody>
  </table>
<% end %>
```

Be **extremely careful**: you must use **i18n** not **I18n**, i18n is yielded by the with_options block.
For *other keys* you just use **I18n** which is not forced in scope.

Comment: Thanks @yerforkferchips for the edit,  I didn't spot the mistake.

Comment: This is great, thank you. It also fails "ungracefully" (actually printing `translation missing` in the view) when I use something like `i18n.t :titl`, which is exactly what I wanted.

Comment: Glad to here. I don't like the syntax so much in that way but you can definitely create a helper like the attributes_for or something similar.

Comment: If I write a nifty helper function, I'll edit it in for future reference.

Answer (score 5):

You can use the `human_attribute_for` method

```
Presentation.human_attribute_for :title
```